# How to reconfigure Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, internationalization

There's an open-source date library(**date-fsn**) that was written in JavaScript and currently I'm working on to add Farsi language but the format of Jalali calendar to the Gregorian calendar is different.

To doing this I want to use the built-in [**Intl API**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl) that it's just available in the browsers. By Default, Node.js doesn't support this API but with a polyfill will be available.

According to [**Node.js documents**](https://github.com/nodejs/node/wiki/Intl#building-node-with-an-embedded-icu), to add other locales I need to install Node.js with special configure and my question is how exactly I can reconfigure Node.js without Reinstallation.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install the [`full-icu`](https://github.com/unicode-org/full-icu-npm) module from npm instead of recompiling node to add support for other languages. It can be installed locally or globally (with `-g`).

Comment: does give me toLocaleString function?

Comment: `date.toLocaleString()` should already exist with small-icu (the default build configuration).